# Transform array from 2 arrays

Tags: php, arrays

**If i have these 2 arrays :**

```
$tables=array('name','phone','alias'); 
$values=array('Jhon','55543232','johny25');
```

How can convert to this kind of array

```
$values=array('name'=>'Jhon','phone'=>'55543232','alias'=>'johny25');
```

I try different ways for transform but i donñt know how i can do , my idea itñs convert this in the fly for automatic process and i think this kind of array are more easy for manage

Thank´s , Regards

Answer (score 1):

Look at [array_combine](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-combine.php)

```
$tables=array('name','phone','alias'); 
$values=array('Jhon','55543232','johny25');
$newarray = array_combine($tables, $values);
```

Answer (score 0):

You're looking for [array_combine](https://www.php.net/array_combine)

```
array_combine(array('name','phone','alias'), array('Jhon','55543232','johny25'))
```

Answer (score 0):

Or you can make an array of array when you are reading your database

```
[0] =>  [phone] => value
        [name]  => value


[1] =>  [phone] => value
        [name]  => value


[2] =>  [phone] => value
        [name]  => value

...ETC
```

How declare ?

$tab[0][0] = array( name => john, phone=>33333 );

$tab[1][0] = array( name => henry, phone=>33333 );

$tab[2][0] = array( name => Marc, phone=>33333 );